# Debugging on the device with multiple Libraries Android

Tags: java, android

I want to debug my application on my Android phone.
However the app itself contains JRE, Maven, and Android Libraries. When I try to run in it does not give me the option to choose my device, but launches the emulator.
The device chooser for "normal apps" works fine. Is it because of multiple libraries I have?

Could anyone please help

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to configuration whether you in RUN/DEBUG mode.

If you using eclipse then use Run > Run Configuration... > Select Tab "Target" > Check "Manual" > Press "Apply" > Press "Run". If device still not show your list, that mean your device how attach properly.

Don't forget to set your device allow to debug. Setting > Application > Check "Unknown Sources".

Hopefully can help you.